# Chamar método de outra classe na mesma aplicação

Tags: android, classes, método

Estou tendo uma grande dificuldade para realizar uma tarefa talvez até simples, para os que estão mais habituados com a linguagem Java no Android.

Tenho uma aplicação que dispões de menus com opções. Uma delas é a de enviar os dados de `TextView`'s à um servidor na net. Nesses `TextView`'s há dois campos: um tópico e uma mensagem. Porém, para enviar eu preciso usar a opção via menu, mas eu queria substituir ela por um botão com evento `onClick()`, estando ele no próprio *layout* em que a opção do menu fica visível. Minha intenção é atribuir ao botão os dados que seriam preenchidos nos `TextView`, de modo a não precisar mais preencher eles (geralmente dados fixos). Com isso, quero embutir no evento do botão.

Tenho a classe que faz o tratamento da leitura dos `TextView` e envio dos dados ao servidor.

Tentei algumas formas: `onClick`, `listener`, mas nada funcionou. O programa rodava nem dava erro de execução, mas o botão ficava sem ação.

Quero usar o método *publish* da classe `Listener`.

Abaixo seque a classe Listener completa:

```
/**
 * Deals with actions performed in the {@link ClientConnections} activity
 * and the {@link ConnectionDetails} activity and associated fragments
 */

public class Listener extends implements OnMenuItemClickListener {

    /**
     * The handle to a {@link Connection} object which contains the {@link MqttAndroidClient} associated with this object
     **/
    private String clientHandle = null;

    /**
     * {@link ConnectionDetails} reference used to perform some actions
     **/
    private ConnectionDetails connectionDetails = null;
    /**
     * {@link ClientConnections} reference used to perform some actions
     **/
    private ClientConnections clientConnections = null;
    /**
     * {@link Context} used to load and format strings
     **/
    private Context context = null;

    /**
     * Whether Paho is logging is enabled
     **/
    static boolean logging = false;

    /**
     * Constructs a listener object for use with {@link ConnectionDetails} activity and
     * associated fragments.
     *
     * @param connectionDetails The instance of {@link ConnectionDetails}
     * @param clientHandle      The handle to the client that the actions are to be performed on
     */

    public Listener(ConnectionDetails connectionDetails, String clientHandle) {
        this.connectionDetails = connectionDetails;
        this.clientHandle = clientHandle;
        context = connectionDetails;

    }

    /**
     * Constructs a listener object for use with {@link ClientConnections} activity.
     *
     * @param clientConnections The instance of {@link ClientConnections}
     */
    public Listener(ClientConnections clientConnections) {
        this.clientConnections = clientConnections;
        context = clientConnections;
    }

    /**
     * Perform the needed action required based on the button that
     * the user has clicked.
     *
     * @param item The menu item that was clicked
     * @return If there is anymore processing to be done
     */

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.publish:
                publish();
                break;
            case R.id.subscribe:
                subscribe();
                break;
            case R.id.newConnection:
                createAndConnect();
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect:
                disconnect();
                break;
            case R.id.connectMenuOption:
                reconnect();
                break;
            case R.id.startLogging:
                enablePahoLogging();
                break;
            case R.id.endLogging:
                disablePahoLogging();
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Reconnect the selected client
     */
    private void reconnect() {
        Connections.getInstance(context).getConnection(clientHandle).changeConnectionStatus(ConnectionStatus.CONNECTING);

        Connection c = Connections.getInstance(context).getConnection(clientHandle);
        try {
            c.getClient().connect(c.getConnectionOptions(), null, new ActionListener(context, Action.CONNECT, clientHandle, null));
        } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Failed to reconnect the client with the handle " + clientHandle, e);
            c.addAction("Client failed to connect");
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Failed to reconnect the client with the handle " + clientHandle, e);
            c.addAction("Client failed to connect");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Disconnect the client
     */
    private void disconnect() {
        Connection c = Connections.getInstance(context).getConnection(clientHandle);

        //if the client is not connected, process the disconnect
        if (!c.isConnected()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            c.getClient().disconnect(null, new ActionListener(context, Action.DISCONNECT, clientHandle, null));
            c.changeConnectionStatus(ConnectionStatus.DISCONNECTING);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Failed to disconnect the client with the handle " + clientHandle, e);
            c.addAction("Client failed to disconnect");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to a topic that the user has specified
     */
    private void subscribe() {
        String topic = ((EditText) connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.topic)).getText().toString();
        ((EditText) connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.topic)).getText().clear();

        RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup) connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.qosSubRadio);
        int checked = radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        int qos = ActivityConstants.defaultQos;

        switch (checked) {
            case R.id.qos0:
                qos = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.qos1:
                qos = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.qos2:
                qos = 2;
                break;
        }

        try {
            String[] topics = new String[1];
            topics[0] = topic;
            Connections.getInstance(context).getConnection(clientHandle).getClient()
                    .subscribe(topic, qos, null, new ActionListener(context, Action.SUBSCRIBE, clientHandle, topics));
        } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Failed to subscribe to" + topic + " the client with the handle " + clientHandle, e);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), "Failed to subscribe to" + topic + " the client with the handle " + clientHandle, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Segue também o xml do layout `Activity_publish` no qual inseri o botão para realizar o evento do menu.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topicGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topictextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dip"
        android:text="@string/topic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastWillTopic"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/topicHint"
        android:inputType="text" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/messageGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/topicGroup"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:text="@string/message" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastWill"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/messageHint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/qosGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/messageGroup"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qosTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/qos" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/qosRadio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qos0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/qos0" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qos1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/qos1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qos2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/qos2" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/retainedGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/qosGroup"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/retainedTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/retained" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/retained"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/retainedGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Enviar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não seria simplesmente adicionar um botão ao layout a atribuir o listener?

```
     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_do_botao);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             publish();
         }
     });
```

Note que o idioma acima usa uma "subclasse anônima" de OnClickListener, evitando ter de declarar uma classe só para isto.

Comment: Adicionei o seguinte trecho logo abaixo da classe Listener. Não gera erro de execução, mas o botão não executa nenhuma ação. No logcat não apareceu nada indicando eventual problema.

Comment: A sugestão de código acima deveria ir no onCreate().

Comment: Sim, eu tinha inserido num onCreate.
`protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {`
`super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_publish);`
`final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);`
`button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

      `public void onClick(View v) {`
      `  publish();`
      `}`
   ` });`
 ` }`

Comment: Teria de colocar um log no próprio método onClick() para ver se pelo menos ele está sendo executado, se sim resta ver o que acontece no publish()

Comment: Fiz o que você disse. Tentei exibir um Toast pelo onClick(), mas sem sucesso. Estranho, pois estava tudo declarado corretamente. Parece que o botão não tem ação, em relação ao método. Percebi que o método publish() possui a seguinte estrutura `connectionDetails.findViewById(R.id.id_do_layout)`. Tentei usá-lo assim, mas ficou exatamente como estava, sem ação. Seria inconveniente eu editar minha pergunta adicionando a classe inteira e as informações de layout para tentar ajudar na avaliação?

Comment: Melhor editar e incluir mais detalhes mesmo... pra ver o que podemos fazer